# node-pre-gyp ERR! Railway app faild. Npm error

Tags: node.js

I hosted my app on railway and it was working perfectly but yesterday it thrown an error of npm. I can't understand what's that and how can solve.
I don't know why this came. I didn't commited anything that cause this error. I just updated the index.html of the app and when I update it, It thrown this npm error. I tried a lot to fix this but couldn't.

```
- yj
 
npm
WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
 
Using npm v8.9.0 from Node
 
Installing node modules
 
npm
WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
 
npm
WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
 
npm WARN deprecated request-promise@4.2.6: request-promise has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
 
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
 
npm WARN deprecated @types/bson@4.2.0: This is a stub types definition. bson provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
 
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
 
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
 
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
 
npm WARN deprecated scrape-yt@1.4.8: Use youtubei instead (https://github.com/SuspiciousLookingOwl/youtubei#readme), it has more features, less buggy, and faster.
 
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.9.0 -> 8.10.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.10.0>;
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.10.0` to update!
npm notice
 
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /workspace/node_modules/canvas
 
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
 
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/bin/node /layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.2.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR!
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.1/canvas-v2.9.1-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR!
node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.1/canvas-v2.9.1-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.9.1 and node@18.2.0 (node-v108 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.1/canvas-v2.9.1-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.2.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm
ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.2.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.2.0/node-v18.2.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.2.0/node-v18.2.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.2.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.2.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR!
gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR!
gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/heroku/.cache/node-gyp/18.2.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm
ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/heroku/.cache/node-gyp/18.2.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/heroku/.cache/node-gyp/18.2.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/workspace/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm
ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pangocairo' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pangocairo --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:261:16)
npm
ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR!
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.0-13-cloud-amd64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/bin/node" "/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR!
gyp ERR! node -v v18.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR!
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR!
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/bin/node /layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR!
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.0-13-cloud-amd64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/bin/node" "/workspace/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR!
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.2.0
gyp ERR! node -v v18.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR!
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR!
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/bin/node /layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR!
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.0-13-cloud-amd64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/layers/heroku_nodejs-engine/dist/bin/node" "/workspace/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR!
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.2.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm
ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
 
 
 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/heroku/.npm/_logs/2022-05-25T04_28_06_162Z-debug-0.log
 
ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
 
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 51
```

**MY PROCFILE:**
`web: npm start`

**MY MANIFEST:**

```yaml
---
applications:
- name: my-app-name
```

I was deloying it to heroku before.

Answer (score 0):

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.1/canvas-v2.9.1-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz
```

It's this line

you (or a dependency) are using a native module and the prebuilt binary is not available for the combo of your node version (18, abi v108), OS (linux) and platform (x64). that's why it's failing back to building from source.

but then

```
npm ERR! Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pangocairo' found
```

`pangocairo` is required to build it from source.

solution: you may have to switch to a prebuilt binary available on github. or you will have to setup the build env to have all the dependencies rquired for building module from source